# how to set a column as unique indexer on Sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite, unique-index

I have 3 columns (_id, column1, column2) _id column has been set as autoincrement

In database there are some duplicate records, so I want to prevent duplicate records with setting column1 as unique indexer. How do I set a column as unique indexer on sqlite? Or how do I prevent duplicate records?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

No magic, just SQL:

```
create table yourtablename (_id  integer primary key autoincrement, column1 text not null unique, column2 text);
```

_id will not be duplicate in any way because it is primary key, column1 neither because it is unique.