# Prevent re-inserting data into Database Tables [Android]

Tags: android, sql, database, android-contentprovider

Right now, I'm working on a project that involves fetching movie data from the MovieDB. I'm using Schematic as my Content Provider Generator to avoid the headache of making one. Works fine so far.

The problem I'm asking here is how my code is structured. Right now, my fragment that includes the AsyncTask calls the task to fetch data, which is called everytime the app loads the MainActivity. Data is fetched and inserted into the database table fine; cursors don't return null and get the data I stored. However, I'm running into this what I believe to be an issue where I fetch the data again and store it into the same database. This happens if I load into a DetailActivity, SettingsActivity, or any other activity that navigates away from the MainActivity but will return to it through a back button.

Log statements appear to show that my data is re-inserting again, resulting in double and so forth of the same entries in the same database table. I can think of a few temporary solutions, one of which is to remove the call to fetch data on starting the app, instead fetching data through the use of a refresh button on the Action Bar. Another is perhaps making a column of the table unique, particularly the youtube video key string that holds the key for a youtube video. I'm still unsure of what to do at this point.

Any solutions I would greatly appreciate. Thanks.

Comment: Couldn't you [set your entry UNIQUE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8544231/how-to-set-a-column-as-unique-indexer-on-sqlite) ?

Comment: I'm gonna try that once I wake up before I sleep after this. Because of how my tables are set up, multiple entries exist for the same movie when they have multiple video links. I'm going to assume Youtube video keys (the # after the watch query parameter in the URI)  are unique.

Comment: Nope, tried it. Setting the constraint unique will make the app crash upon trying to reinsert

Comment: You need to check if it already exists before re-inserting ...

Answer (score 0):

Add `Unique` or `Primary` key with `replace` as conflict resolution.

Something like this

```
@DataType(DataType.Type.INTEGER)
@PrimaryKey(onConflict = ConflictResolutionType.REPLACE)
String UNIQUE_COLUMN = "unique_column";
```

It works with `@PrimaryKey`,`@Unique` and `@Check`. More information can be found in [Schematic's JavaDoc](https://github.com/SimonVT/schematic/blob/master/schematic-annotations/src/main/java/net/simonvt/schematic/annotation/PrimaryKey.java) and SQlite's [ON CONFLICT](https://sqlite.org/lang_conflict.html) documentation.

There are some limitations:

- Schematic will ignore `onConflict` if multiple `@PrimaryKey` are present
- resolution `Replace` will replace all columns in a row, not just columns, provided in insert.