# SQLite table constraint unique and ON CONFLICT REPLACE usage

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, unique-constraint

**Please read before make it Duplicate.**

I am trying to insert longitude and latitude values in SQLite table and i want it to be unique value, after some research for that i have found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2701903/5476209) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8544256/5476209) answers very helpful, although they both are written for simple queries and i am not able to find how to fit my query with both constraints **unique** and **ON_CONFLICTION_REPLACE**

query is as follow,

```
 private static final String CREATE_USER_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_LOCATIONS + "("
                + UID + " TEXT PRIMARY KEY," + ADDRESS + " TEXT,"
                + LONGITUDE + " TEXT unique," + LATITUDE + " TEXT unique" + ")";
```

but this unique doesn't made any differences, is it compulsion to use `ON_CONFLICTION_REPLACE` in my case?

From [Ayman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/40005/ayman-hourieh)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2701877/sqlite-table-constraint-unique-on-multiple-columns/2701903#2701903) i got that i can apply unique on multiple columns together but i still getting duplicate values after insertion. can anyone make appropriate query from my query and help me understand all things? Thanks

Comment: Are you looking for unique constraint in latitude and longitude combined or individual unique constraints for latitude and longitude separately?

Comment: no i want it for both i mean set of Long and Lat @Samuel

Answer (score 1):

Change your table structure to this

```
private static final String CREATE_USER_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_LOCATIONS + "("
            + UID + " TEXT PRIMARY KEY," + ADDRESS + " TEXT,"
            + LONGITUDE + " TEXT," + LATITUDE + " TEXT,
            UNIQUE(" + LOGITUDE + "," + LATITUDE + ") ON CONFLICT REPLACE)";
```

Then when you do the insert use the below method

```
ContentValues insertValues = new ContentValues();
insertValues.put(LATITUDE, latitude);
insertValues.put(LOGITUDE, longitude);
db.insertWithOnConflict(TABLE_LOCATIONS, null, insertValues, SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_REPLACE);
```

Comment: but what is issue with simple insert method ? Because after applying your query it still taking repeated values.

Comment: Have tried uninstalling the existing apk? The new table definition will be reflected only once you recreate the database.

Comment: no still not working i always getting incremental row value of long returned from db.insert method @SamuelRobert

Comment: Can you post your insert function?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123688/discussion-between-tapanhp-and-samuel-robert).